# How do I remove GnuPG encryption when backing up using duplicity?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gnupg, duplicity

I have tried this command:

```
duplicity full --s3-use-new-style --no-encryption /Location s3+http://${bucket}/${folder}
```

but it still encrypts the file on my s3 folder. What I want is when I run the command and the /Location folder contains txt1, txt2, txt3, I will see txt1, txt2, txt3 on my s3 folder.

Thanks :)